# JWPLAYER customization and Audio streaming

Tags: amazon-web-services, streaming, jwplayer

I have two questions using `JWPLAYER`. I have searched in many places but didn't get the answer, especially regarding `audio streaming` in `JWPLAYER`.

**Question1:**

I am working on transcoding the video files into `m3u8` and `ts` chunks using `aws-elastic-transcoder` and successfull streaming videos.

Now, I want to stream the audio files.

Does audio files follow the same process of dividing into `m3u8` and `ts` chunks. What extra configurations does it need. What audio files are supported, **I also need audio HD quality toggling in audio**. How do I achieve it?

**Question2:**

I want to customize my `JWPLAYER`, especially `AUDIO player`. I want to add different buttons into the `control-bar`.

- A shuffle button
- An image in the control bar
- A download button
- A button to show the current queue list.( How to add an audio file
  HLS to queue)
- A repeat button
- A settings Button

So, basically I want to customize the complete player. How can I achieve this. How can I change the whole JWPLAYER HTML.

Please give any reference URL if available.

Here are my options,

```
JWOptions = {
      id: "myPlayer2",
       "playlist": [{
         "file": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/mypath1/index.m3u8",
         "image": "assets/img/bg1.jpg",
         "title": "Sintel Trailer",
         "mediaid": "ddra573"
       }, {
         "file": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/mypath2/index.m3u8",
         "image": "assets/img/bg2.jpg",
         "title": "Big Buck Bunny Trailer",
         "mediaid": "ddrx3v2"
       }],
      width: 800,
      height: 40,
    }
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

about 1): you can convert in AAC (m4a) audio files like for video. You can use AAC-LC codec for non high quality, and HE-AAC for high quality audio. jwPlayer setup is the same of video, it works, but you can setup better according to your needs.

about 2): you can add an item to the controlbar like in this example http://codepen.io/fdambrosio/pen/XRpBvW but I think that adding 4 or 5 more items  does not fit well into the default jwplayer controlbar, because in mobile/small size the controlbar is minimal and jwplayer shows items with different style thank desktop.

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id='radioplayer'></div> 
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#change-speed {font-size: 16px; color: white; padding-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px;}
```

JS:

```
 var playerInstance = jwplayer("radioplayer");
    playerInstance.setup({
    file:'//video.radioradicale.it:1935/store-86/_definst_/mp4:2015/01/MQ781257.mp4/playlist.m3u8',
    width:544, 
  height: 306,
  androidhls: true,
  autostart: true,
});

var tag;

    jwplayer("radioplayer").on('ready', function(){

        if (jwplayer("radioplayer").getProvider().name == "html5" | jwplayer("radioplayer").getProvider().name == "shaka") {
            console.log('1X');
            var normale = document.createElement("div");
            normale.id = "change-speed";
            normale.setAttribute('class','jw-reset jw-text jw-icon-inline');
            normale.innerHTML = "1x";
            document.getElementsByClassName('jw-controlbar-right-group')[0].appendChild(normale);

              tag = document.querySelector('video');
              tag.defaultPlaybackRate = 1.0;
              tag.playbackRate = 1.0;

              $('#change-speed').on('click', function() {
        console.log('test');
              speed_bfr = tag.playbackRate;

              console.log(speed_bfr, 'prima');
              switch(speed_bfr) {
                case 1.0: 
                console.log('1.0');
                normale.innerHTML = "1.5x";
                tag.playbackRate = 1.5;
                break;

                case 1.5:
                console.log('1.5');
                normale.innerHTML = "1x";
                tag.playbackRate = 1.0;
                break;

              }

            });

        }
    });
```

You can also add only one button (ex. download) over poster image, as described here: https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/demos/basic/add-download-button/

Otherwise you can develop your custom controlbar, or adding buttons near the player, using JwPlayer API: https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/docs/javascript-api-reference/